# How can I get the data in my array object to my jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jstree

Hi I was wondering how can i get the data of my array object to my jstree..

For example I have this array object(this is the response in my console for listing folders in my dropbox)

```
    0:Object
       .tag:"folder"
        id:"id:dEOW7ElDHUgAAAAAAAAABw"
        name:"Yahoo! Mail"
        path_display:"/Yahoo! Mail"
        path_lower:"/yahoo! mail"
  1:Object
       .tag:"folder"
        id:"id:dEOW7ElDHUgAAAAAAAAAJg"
        name:"Sample Folder"
        path_display:"/Sample Folder"
        path_lower:"/sample folder"

  2:Object
       .tag:"folder"
        id:"id:dEOW7ElDHUgAAAAAAAAAJw"
        name:"Sample Folder 1"
        path_display:"/Sample Folder 1"
        path_lower:"/sample folder 1"
```

I tried this code but there's no folders shown I tried to console it and the response is the 3 objects in the top

```
          $("#people").jstree({
                        // generating tree from json data
                        "json_data" : {
                            "data" : [{
                                    "data": response.entries,

                                }]

                        },
                        // plugins used for this tree
                        "plugins" : [ "json_data", "ui", "types" ]
                    })
```

Comment: What have you tried? Dropbox HTTP API `list_folder` returns a JSON. So you just need to map the API response to the jstree compatible format as explained in https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/

Comment: I edited my code the response.entries is from the response api in dropbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to map the data following jstree standard. This is a basic example based on given data:

```js
var response = {
  "entries": [{
    "tag": "folder",
    "id": "id:dEOW7ElDHUgAAAAAAAAABw",
    "name": "Yahoo! Mail",
    "path_display": "/Yahoo! Mail",
    "path_lower": "/yahoo! mail"
  }, {
    "tag": "folder",
    "id": "id:dEOW7ElDHUgAAAAAAAAAJg",
    "name": "Sample Folder",
    "path_display": "/Sample Folder",
    "path_lower": "/sample folder"
  }, {
    "tag": "folder",
    "id": "id:dEOW7ElDHUgAAAAAAAAAJw",
    "name": "Sample Folder 1",
    "path_display": "/Sample Folder 1",
    "path_lower": "/sample folder 1"
  }]
}

// map data to jstree standard
response.entries.forEach(function(entry) {
 if (entry.tag == 'folder') {
   entry.parent = '#'
  }
  entry.text = entry.name
})

$('#jstree').jstree({
  'core': {
    'data': response.entries
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="jstree"></div>
```